# SQL Server Denominator Pushed to Zero

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following formula to calculate the Pearson correlation in my data. Note: I am using a `CASE WHEN` to account for a divide by zero error. The code below represents solely the formula.

```
( COUNT(*) * SUM(X * Y) - SUM(X) * SUM(Y) ) 
/ ( SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(X * X) - SUM(X) * SUM(x)) * SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(Y* Y) - SUM(Y) * SUM(Y) ) )
```

**Edit** added query:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;
    SELECT year
           ,product_id
           ,score_range
           ,reporting_year
        /* used to manually calculate correlation in excel */
           ,COUNT(*) AS n_count
           ,COUNT(*) * SUM(1_x * 2_score) - SUM(1_x) * SUM(2_score) AS numerator
           ,SUM(1_x * 1_x) AS 1_sumprod
           ,SUM(1_x) AS 1_sum
           ,SUM(2_score * 2_score) AS 2_sumprod
           ,SUM(2_score) AS 2_sum
    INTO #test
    FROM #acct_details
    GROUP BY year
             ,product_id
             ,score_range
             ,reporting_year
    ;


    SELECT year
           ,product_id
           ,score_range
           ,reporting_year
           ,CASE 
                WHEN ( ( SQRT(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum) * SQRT(n_count * 2_sumprod - 2_sum * 2_sum) ) )  = 0
                THEN NULL
                ELSE numerator / ( ( SQRT(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum) * SQRT(n_count * 2_sumprod - 2_sum * 2_sum) ) ) 
            END AS sql_corr
            ,(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum) 1_denom
            ,( SQRT(n_count * 2_sumprod - 2_sum * 2_sum) ) AS 2_denom
    FROM #test
    ORDER BY year
             ,reporting_year
             ,score_range
     ;
```

The output of my data looks like the table below. Note that `excel_corr` is the correlation manually calculated in Excel, which is my expected output.
The column `sql_corr`  is the result from my sql code above. The columns from `count` to the end represent the X and Y values that get plugged into the formula above. My problem is that the `sql_corr` does not match the output from manually calculating the correlation by groupings in Excel.

```
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| year | product_id | score_range | reporting_year | sql_corr | count | numerator | 1_sumprod | 1_sum     | 2_sumprod | 2_sum   | excel_corr |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 1-2         | 2016           | NULL     | 1     | 0         | 0.000124  | -0.011155 | 195364    | 442     | #DIV/0!    |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 3-4         | 2016           | NULL     | 1272  | -0.0683   | 4.9E-11   | -0.000007 | 304648060 | 622434  | -0.02911   |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 5-6         | 2016           | -0.06416 | 3913  | -11.845   | 2.89E-09  | -0.000459 | 1.089E+09 | 2063948 | -0.06391   |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 7-8         | 2016           | 0.00573  | 2593  | 1.63663   | 2.27E-08  | -0.000975 | 848560006 | 1482872 | 0.00573    |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 9-10        | 2016           | -0.02106 | 1420  | -3.2855   | 4.13E-08  | -0.00131  | 555096971 | 887587  | -0.02106   |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 11-12       | 2016           | 0.05231  | 917   | 6.64768   | 1.06E-07  | -0.000987 | 413059274 | 615312  | 0.052438   |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 13-14       | 2016           | 0.006704 | 359   | 0.5064    | 6.18E-07  | 0.000271  | 185781413 | 258205  | 0.006705   |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 15-16       | 2016           | 0.017846 | 55    | 0.14095   | 3.79E-06  | 0.000349  | 31849498  | 41850   | 0.017839   |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 2016 | 1          | 17-18       | 2016           | NULL     | 1     | 0         | 0         | 0         | 641601    | 801     | #DIV/0!    |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

For example, in `score_range` `3-4` the `sql_corr` value is `NULL` but in excel the value is `-0.02911`.  If we plug in the values manually into the formula `-0.02911` is the correct result.

```
numerator 
/ ( ( SQRT(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum) * SQRT(n_count * 2_sumprod - 2_sum * 2_sum) ) )
```

In SQL Server the denominator is getting pushed to 0. When I calculate this manually in Excel the denominator is 2.344354. Why is my denominator being pushed to 0 in SQL Server when the same data results in a different calculation when done manually?

**Edit**
The first part of the denominator is being pushed to 0. `( ( SQRT(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum)`. When the multiplication occurs the whole denominator gets pushed to 0 in SQL activating the CASE statement to return NULL. This is incorrect confirmed by manual calculation. The following represents the output from both parts of the denominator 0.000000 and 9394.0387480572. The actual value for the first part of the denominator via manual calculation is ~0.00025.

**Edit**
The value of `(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum)` = 6.2279E-08 -- before taking the square root. However, SQL is pushing this part of the equation to 0.

I am using SQL Server 2016 v14.0.2037.2. I thought maybe my value was too small but it appears that values greater than 5E-18 should remain. This was confirmed in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016).

Comment: Where is your T-SQL query?

Comment: For which record the denominator must be 2.344354 ?

Comment: My example occurs when `score_range` is 3-4

Comment: added query as well

Comment: I would check if your numerator and/or denominator are evaluating to null. That could also cause a null result.

Comment: The first part of the denominator is being pushed to 0. `( ( SQRT(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum)`.  Thus when the multiplication occurs the whole denominator gets pushed to 0 in SQL activating the `CASE` statement to return `NULL`. This is incorrect confirmed by manual calculation. The following represents the output from both parts of the denominator `0.000000` and `9394.0387480572`

Comment: Could one of your values in the calculation be null. That would force the result to null even when your denominator !=0.

Comment: I am not seeing where 1_num is defined?

Comment: Good suggestion. I double checked all the records used to generate each part of the calculation. None of the values are `NULL` and the table represents the result of each individual part of the calculation and there isn't a `NULL`. As for `1_num` that was a type-o resulting for cleaning my code to post it on here. Updated.

Comment: It seems like The value of `(n_count * 1_sumprod - 1_sum * 1_sum)` = 6.2279E-08 -- before taking the square root. However, SQL is pushing this part of the equation to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to TomPhillips [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/265768/value-gets-pushed-to-zero.html).

> They problem you have is you have a mix of integers and floats. This causes confusions and conversions. Convert all your values to float to get the value you are expecting. This is what Excel does.

Even though I CAST the initial values going into `#test` from `#acct_details` as DECIMAL, I needed to explicitly CAST the values in `#test` to the formula all as DECIMAL also. The result kept getting rounded to 0 here: `SUM(1_x * 1_x)`. `CAST`ing the values explicitly resolved this by forcing the necessary precision.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;
    SELECT year
           ,product_id
           ,score_range
           ,reporting_year
        /* used to manually calculate correlation in excel */
           ,CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) AS n_count
           ,CAST( ( COUNT(*) * SUM(1_x * 2_score) - SUM(1_x) * SUM(2_score) ) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) AS numerator
           ,CAST(SUM(1_x * 1_x) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) AS 1_sumprod
           ,CAST(SUM(1_x) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) AS 1_sum
           ,CAST(SUM(2_score * 2_score) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) AS 2_sumprod
           ,CAST(SUM(2_score) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) AS 2_sum
    INTO #test
    FROM #acct_details
    GROUP BY year
             ,product_id
             ,score_range
             ,reporting_year
    ;
```

Changing them to `FLOAT` also worked. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016).

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;
    SELECT year
           ,product_id
           ,score_range
           ,reporting_year
        /* used to manually calculate correlation in excel */
           ,CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) AS n_count
           ,CAST( ( COUNT(*) * SUM(1_x * 2_score) - SUM(1_x) * SUM(2_score) ) AS FLOAT) AS numerator
           ,CAST(SUM(1_x * 1_x) AS FLOAT) AS 1_sumprod
           ,CAST(SUM(1_x) AS FLOAT) AS 1_sum
           ,CAST(SUM(2_score * 2_score) AS FLOAT) AS 2_sumprod
           ,CAST(SUM(2_score) AS FLOAT) AS 2_sum
    INTO #test
    FROM #acct_details
    GROUP BY year
             ,product_id
             ,score_range
             ,reporting_year
    ;
```